# LinqDataSource wizard table list is not refreshing after updating LinqToSql classes

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2008, linq-to-sql, linqdatasource

I have changed my dbml file like this.

- I have deleted all the tables and stored procs.
- I added new tables and stored procs from a new database.

In the code-behind, I can access the new tables and stored procs. However, in the `LinqDataSource` using the same dbContext when I'm trying to configure the `LinqDataSource`. I can see all the old tables in the wizard drop-down.

How to refresh the the wizard drop-down so that I can select the newly added tables?

Deleting the old `LinqDataSource`and adding a new one is not working.

Comment: Did you ever get a fix for this, I'm facing exactly the same problem having tried the same things.

Answer (score 3):

After creating your new dbml, rebuild the solution. The tables should be shown in the wizard then.